# how to change location of visual studio folder 2017 that is created automatically while creating a project

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am trying to change folder name "Visual Studio 2017" that is created automatically whenever i try to open a new windows application. I've read all the answers related to How to change "Visual Studio 2017" folder location? method that is discussed in this context like didn't work for me. currently i am using visual studio 2017 community edition.

I tried to change "registry edit" method. but can't find how to change those values like where to find and save default folder method, although method involving " tools >> options >> projects and solutions >> Locations" worked for me. that is to be changed. also

please explain all steps clearly. thanking you If possible upload snapshots of all the steps.

Answer (score 0):

Do not **ever** mess up with the registry, because you don't know what you're doing and you might screw up other parts of Visual Studio and get many side reactions.

To answer your question, go to **Options - Projects and Solutions - Locations**. You can change the folder from there.

Comment: I tried this method, but ArchitectureExplorer,codesnipets,backup files,start page and templates are still getting created in documents folder.

Comment: Then try reinstalling and put the correct directories in the first place.